# jQuery unwrap is not working

Tags: jquery, html, unwrap

I'm trying to use unwrap to remove an parent element.   I'm following the documentation and yet it doesn't work; I have Html Like this:
    
        test html

and I wrote this function to clone and unwrap it:

```
var htmlTemplate = $('#htmlTemplate').clone().removeAttr('id').unwrap();
```

When I run this code the template still has the outer span on it.
Does anyone know how to unwrap this properly?

Comment: you have to unwrap it two times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To unwrap an element it should have a parent. You are creating a DOM fragment and trying to unwrap it. But it has no parents.

Say, there's some dom:

```
<button>unwrap</button>
<div class="outer"></div>
```

With the parent in place unwraping goes just fine:

```
var inner = '<span class="inner">test html</span>',
        $outer = $('.outer');

// First you would want your element to get a parent.
$outer.html(inner);


// Then unwrap it
$('button').on('click', function() {
    $('.inner').unwrap();
});
```

here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Patat/f0q36s8w/1/)

So, if you want to remove the outer span, you should target the inner one and it will unwrap.

**For the updated fragment:**
.clone() doesn't copy any parents it copies only the element and all it's descendants. So when you use clone - you build a separate fragment with root at the selected element.

.unwrap() removes the parent(s) of the matched element(s). So to unwrap the inner span you must select it with jQuery.

```
<div class="outer"></div>
```

js

```
var html = "<span><span class='inner'>test html </span></span>";

var $html = $(html);

var unwraped = $html.find('.inner').unwrap();

$('.outer').html(unwraped);
```

another [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Patat/cdnv46bx/3/)

**Upd:**

There's difference between traversing the DOM and modifying it. When you use .find() - you are traversing (moving from element to element). The structure of the DOM tree stays the same. When you use .unwrap() - you are altering the structure (removing an element from the DOM).

Comment: this didn't fully answer my question but I understand what Im doing wrong now so thanks

Comment: as you said before unwrap doesn't work on fragments, so you can just call $html.find('.inner')

Comment: also that will only work if there is a single element inside of the span it would probably be better just to call $(html).html()

Comment: to understand better, read about what $(htmlString) is http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2

Comment: unwrap works on fragments. if those fragments have parents. I used find to access a child within the created fragment. Only a child can be unwraped.

Comment: when you call find on the html you already have lost the parent, the call to unwrap isn't doing anything

Comment: yes. and no. .find does not affect the DOM tree. .unwrap does - here in console. https://jsfiddle.net/Patat/cdnv46bx/4/

Comment: Interesting, you right something is deffinetly different when I call it logs different objects when I call https://jsfiddle.net/cdnv46bx/11/

Answer (score 1):

**Unwrap not working for string its working for DOM elements.**

The .unwrap() method removes the element's parent. This is effectively the inverse of the .wrap() method. The matched elements (and their siblings, if any) replace their parents within the DOM structure.

For more detail:https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/

```js
var html = $('span'); 
html.unwrap('span');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="html">
  <span><span>test html </span></span>
<p>
```

Comment: What happens when you call clone is that convert it to a string?

Answer (score 0):

Try to `unwrap` like below

```
var html = "<span><span>test html</span></span>"
html = $(html).unwrap();
$(html).unwrap();
```

Comment: I just want to remove one span not both

Answer (score 0):

> The `.unwrap()` method removes the element's parent.

So to say, `span` has to be an element.

```js
var gameOfThronesChars = $('p'); // Create an element.

$( "button" ).click(function() {
  if ( gameOfThronesChars.parent().is( "div" ) ) {
    gameOfThronesChars.unwrap();
  } else {
    gameOfThronesChars.wrap( "<div></div>" );
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>


<style type="text/css">
  div {
    border: 2px solid #c00;
  }
</style>

<button>Wrap/Unwrap</button>

<p>Tyrion Lannister</p>
<p>Cersei Lannister</p>
<p>Sansa Stark</p>
<p>Arya Stark</p>
```

Comment: @iamjoshuamabina I've update my question to reflect the actual code example properly